# using variable in link in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I've learned that I can use a button to link someone to another page like this:

```
$("#something").append("<br><center><input type='button' value='Go' onclick='location.href=\"http://www.google.com\"'></center>");
```

But let's say I wanted to use a variable as the address, I'm not sure how to do that. What I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
var url = "http://www.google.com";
$("#something").append("<br><center><input type='button' value='Go' onclick='location.href=url'></center>");
```

Can someone please correct my error? Thanks

Comment: Is this really a `<center>` tag that I see ? use `text-align:center` or `width` + `margin:auto` instead

Answer (score 5):

You can concatenate url variable in the string like this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bghkq/)**

```
$("#something").append("<br><center><input type='button' 
value='Go' onclick='location.href=" +url+ "'></center>");
```

Comment: Are you missing the escaped quotes (`\"`) around the url?

Comment: still seems to not be working... I think it is because I'm missing the escaped quotes, where would I add these?